# MongoDB failed to start due to FileNotOpen

Tags: mongodb, installation, crash

Recently I have been getting this issue alot on my Ubuntu-based Distro (Zoren 16)
I tried reinstalling MongoDB but it didn't help.

```
➜ sudo service mongod status    
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-06-21 16:43:50 IST; 3min 47s ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 45583 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 45583 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Jun 21 16:43:50 abhinav-OMEN systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jun 21 16:43:50 abhinav-OMEN mongod[45583]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-06-21T11:13:50.918Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed to open /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}
Jun 21 16:43:50 abhinav-OMEN systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 21 16:43:50 abhinav-OMEN systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Due to this i'm unable to connect to my local mongodb server.

Comment: Does `/var/log/mongodb/` exist, and is it writable by the mongod user?

Comment: No, shouldn't it get auto generated?

Comment: possibly.  I have seen systems configured to wipe the /var partition on reboot, so it never hurts to check.

Comment: Alright, so I solved this with the instructions in my answer given, this behavior is pretty weird, also if you have a way to setup a "ignore/disable /var wipe" or similar, let me in the loop!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PS: I need to remove monogodb, reinstall it, and then use this command for some reason---

Running this worked for me ---

```
[sudo] chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
[sudo] chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

# create a new file if not present
[sudo] touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log 
[sudo] chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
[sudo] service mongod restart
```

Comment: Also, if you ever start mongod as root, you will need to fix these permissions again

Comment: I rebooted my computer (local DB), then mongoDB wouldn't start, for some reason. The first 2 lines fixed it. Although I had never changed user rights. I have no explanation for what went wrong.